# AngularJS: strange two-way-binding (isolated scope) behaviour when using callbacks within a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-directive

I am currently writing a directive with an isolated scope. Within this scope I am changing the values of the binded variables. After changing the values I am calling a callback function that uses these variables for further processing steps.

Based on the official documentation samples I have created an simplified plunkr of my problem http://plnkr.co/edit/48WscOc1o9XcQlBxSeEH?p=info

As you can see the name of the customer is passed to the directive where its value is changed when clicking on the name. After changing the name I'm calling the provided function where the corresponding variable from the scope is printed to the console. As you can see in the console, with the first click the variable customer.name has still the old value "Naomi", while the template value has changed.

Is this an intended behaviour?

Comment: possible duplicate of [anglar js setting model value from directive and calling a parent scope function holds on to the previous value inside that function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145191/anglar-js-setting-model-value-from-directive-and-calling-a-parent-scope-function)

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507318/the-difference-and-relationship-between-the-scope-passed-in-a-controller-and-t/39507512#39507512 I hope it helps!