# The difference and relationship between the $scope passed in a controller, and the $scope passed in a directive

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, angularjs-directive, scope, angular-controller

What is the difference and relationship between the `$scope` passed in a `controller`, and the `$scope` passed in a `directive`?

And how would you set these up?

Comment: @BuhBuh these are wiki answer, you decide to create a question for people that might need those informations and answer it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a brief explanation of what is the difference and relationship between the `$scope` passed in a `controller`, and the `$scope` passed in a `directive` is:**

As you can see form the basic Angular setup below, `$scope` is passed to both the `Angular Controller` and to the `Angular Directive`. But what are the differences, and how do these `$scope`s relate and interact with each other?

**Basic Angular Setup**

**Angular App:**

```
angular.module('app', []);
```

**Angular Controller:**

```
angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: 'Luke Skywalker',
    address: {
      street: 'PO Box 123',
      city: 'Secret Rebel Base',
      planet: 'Yavin 4'
    },
    friends: [
      'Han',
      'Leia',
      'Chewbacca'
    ]
  }
});
```

**Angular Directive:**

```
angular.module('app').directive('userInfoCard', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: "userInfoCard.html",
    restrict: "E",
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.knightMe = function(user) {
        user.rank = "knight";
      }
    }
  }
});
```

There are 3 ways you can set up the relationship between the `directive scope` and the containing `controller scope`:

The default is for the `directive` to ***share*** the scope with the containing `controller`. This diagram illustrates this relationship.

**Directive Scope - Shared**

You can see the parent `$scope` in purple, and we can see our `User object` created on the Parent `Controller`. The directive with the shared $scope lives entirely in the parent `controller's $scope`, and it has access to every object on the parent's `controller $scope`.

If the directive had to modify or add items to the $scope, it would belong to the `parent controller's $scope` and not the `directive`. You can easily see this if you had to add a line to the `controller` and the `directive` to log out the `$scope` `(console.log($scope);`). You will note the **$id** of both **ChildScopes** would be the same.

Shared Scope is the simplest way to deal with `$scope` in `directives`.

[image]

**Directive Inherited Scope**

The following diagram illustrates `directive` inherited `$scope`:

[image]

*Diagram 1*

We once again have a user object created in the controller $scope, but with the directive set up to have inherited $scope.

When we create a new item in the `directive $scope`, it will become **Internal Data**, and not visible to the parent `$scope`. In other words that item will live on the `directive $scope` and not on the parent `$scope`.

**See diagram 2 below**:

[image]

*Diagram 2*

There are several reasons why you would want to do this, the most common would be to **encapsulate** the data inside the `directive`.

To create a directive with inherited `$scope`, you add a `scope` `property` to the directive, and set it to `true` (setting it to `false` would be shared `$scope` - which is the default in any case).

See `directive` code below:

**Angular Directive:**

```
angular.module('app').directive('userInfoCard', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: "userInfoCard.html",
    restrict: "E",
    scope: true,
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.knightMe = function(user) {
        user.rank = "knight";
      }
    }
  }
});
```

When you log this out via the console, you will notice 2 ChildScope objects as before. But this time the **$id** is different for each `$scope` object.

**One thing to note**: the `directive` ChildScope object has a property called **$parent**. This has the same **$id** as the `controller` ChildScope object. So the containing `controller $scope` has been set as the **$parent** of the `directive $scope`. You will also note the **user** object is visible in the **parent** `$scope`. This is true JavaScript **inheritance**.

Note: You will notice that the directive ChildScope object has a **prototype** (`_proto_`). When you look at the prototype, you can see that this is also that same scope object of the directive, making this true inheritance.

**Read:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

http://javascript.info/tutorial/inheritance

**The main difference here is not what the child scope can see on the parent scope, but instead what happens when the child scope creates new data. This data is internal to the child scope and not visible to the parent scope.**

**Isolated Scope**

The diagram below illustrates this scenario:

[image]

Once again we have a parent `controller` `$scope` that contains a **user** object. And as with **inherited** `$scope`, the data created in the `directive` `$scope` will be **internal** and **not visible** to the `controller` `$scope`.

But we have the issue of the `directive $scope` not being able to see the data on the `controller $scope`. Often we would want to see certain data elements of the `controller $scope`.

To solve this you can create a special binding between the isolated `$scope` and the parent `$scope` on an object by object basis. This way the isolated `$scope` cannot see everything on the parent `$scope`, but it can see specific items you make visible.

To do this, you change the **true** on the **scope** property to an **object {}**.

If you had to log this to the console, you would see once again that each ChildScope objects has its own unique **$id**. You will also note that the child scope (`directive`) still has a **$parent** object that is the parent scope (`controller`), but this time there is no parent scope linked to the **prototype**.

To make the **user** object of the `controller` visible to the scope of the `directive`, you can add a property to the directive scope object of "user", and set its value to "=", telling the scope to expect an object to be passed to it with the value of "user".

**The code below demonstrates this:**

```
angular.module('app').directive('userInfoCard', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: "userInfoCard.html",
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      user: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.collapsed = ($scope.initialCollapsed === 'true');
      $scope.knightMe = function(user) {
        user.rank = "knight";
      }
      $scope.collapse = function() {
        $scope.collapsed = !$scope.collapsed;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And that is the 3 ways to set up the relationship between the `directive` scope and the containing `controller` scope.

A special thanks to Joe Eames. https://github.com/joeeames